# Download archive from glacier, using their HI-Level API (in their java SDK)

Tags: java, amazon-glacier

What happens when I download an archive from glacier using the Java SDK's high-level API and the program is interrupted?

If I use a low-level API, I can send a request to prepare my download, and then after hours download it. I don't need to run my application all the time between these actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the the behaviour of the `ArchiveTransferManager` class.

My reading of the code is that if the first phase (fetching from deep storage) is interrupted, then the manager will attempt to delete the jobs and job queues associated with the manager instance.

It also looks like the manager will respond to a Java thread interrupt by stopping whatever operation it is currently doing.  It looks like you will get an `AmazonClientException` with a message saying that the operation was interrupted.

Note that this behaviour is not specified in the javadocs.

Reference:

- [source code link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.8.0/com/amazonaws/services/glacier/transfer/ArchiveTransferManager.java#ArchiveTransferManager.download%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.io.File%2Ccom.amazonaws.event.ProgressListener%29) (version 1.8.0)

Comment: Ok. it looks like i shood use low-api. Thank you.

Comment: @glebiuskv - I recommend that you try reading the code yourself.  It is well written ...